# How could I exchange the editor and viewer windows in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

I would like to **exchange** the editor and the viewer in TeXstudio, for convenience.
[image]

[image: exchange windows]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the only TeXstudio inbuilt function that comes near to your wish is first to switch viewer to "windowed" then use "side by side" as seen here

[image]

However note that there is an odd gap between the windows and it would be simpler to let windows do a split screen without the gap by simply dragging each window to the corresponding edge like this.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your response, but when I compile, it changes to the viewer window, and I would like to continue in the editor window to continue writing.

Comment: The shift of focus is often desired during compile to show the last edit in the pdf, however there are several settings in the windowed viewer Window > focus editor and in window Configure I think there are more settings to control the synching but if you only build (F6=single green arrow) NOT build and view (double green arrow) it will stay in the editor I also have in configure build advanced options "don't launch a new instance of the viewer if pdf is already opened"